# Extending Commerce server2007 PurchaseOrder

Tags: microsoft-commerce-server

A purchase order can be stored in Commerce Server 2007 in the purchaseorders table, which comes with a limited default storage columns. What if you want to add new columns to this table that would be used to store additional order information?

Pls Note that I am a beginner in Commerce server 2007

Thanks in Advance

KP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the PurchaseOrders table in two ways.  Both involve adding additional data to the `PurchaseOrder` class and mapping that to a new column in the database:

1. **Map a weakly typed PurchaseOrder class property to a new database column**.  [How to Map a Weakly Typed Indexer Property to an Explicit Database Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545791.aspx) documents this and explicitly mentions the PurchaseOrder scenario.  There is also relevant material in the blog post [Mapping Weakly Typed Properties to Storage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vkumar/archive/2006/06/28/649940.aspx).
2. **Derive a new class from PurchaseOrder and add a property**.  Read [How to Derive a New Orders Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms944267.aspx) and [How to Modify the Orders Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545988.aspx) to get a feel for this.  Also, see the entire section [Extending the Orders Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms964374.aspx).  Finally, there is an [example of the entire process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219308.aspx), but applied to the LineItem class.

**Important Note:** While the first approach is quicker, it has some limitations when using the CS BizTalk adapters.  For example, *I don't think* you can use a weakly typed property to correlate.  However, my memory is hazy on this (just remember getting bitten by something along those lines).